# plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project Error

Tags: maven

Below is a sample of a Hello World gcloud and maven based code

```
    <!-- [START pom] -->
.
.
.

<!-- [START properties] -->
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <!-- REQUIRED by appengine-maven-plugin plugin, if web.xml does not exist for your application -->
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
<!-- [END_EXCLUDE] -->
.
.
.
  <build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <!-- [START cloudplugin] -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- [END cloudplugin] -->
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
<!-- [END pom] -->
```

And upon running the mvn appengine:run command I get the following error:

"No plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/luay/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]"

Answer (score 0):

Maven may somehow not updating your local repository, you may run your command `mvn appengine:run -U` and try your luck; by -U, you mean to say update repository.

Also can you check your m2 directory and verify if you have these jars `~/.m2/repository/com/google/cloud/tools/appengine-maven-plugin/`, if you are on windows `~` is C:/Users/